# Chain of words made by words in the list

Tags: algorithm

I am stuck at a programming question. I need help!
The question is as follows. Given a list of words I have to return true if it is possible to create a chain of words as follows.

cat tab bat etc. i.e end letter of a word has to be start of the other in the chain.

 How should I implement this?
I can only think of the brute force solution where I generate all permutations of a list and then check if any of it meets the conditions.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe keeping a count of how many words start/end with each letter would help.

Comment: This is essentially a version of the [Hamiltonian Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) problem, which is NP complete. Each node is a word, and you draw a directed edge between two nodes if one word starts with the letter that the other word ends with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a directed graph which has a vertex for each letter, and an edge for each word.

So the word "cat" would correspond to a directed edge from vertex "c" to vertex "t".

In this graph you are trying to see whether there is an [Eulerian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

Checking for an Eulerian path can be done as described on the wiki page:

> A directed graph has an Eulerian trail if and only if at most one
>   vertex has (out-degree) − (in-degree) = 1, at most one vertex has
>   (in-degree) − (out-degree) = 1, every other vertex has equal in-degree
>   and out-degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to
>   a single connected component of the underlying undirected graph.

### Example

[image]

In this picture we can travel all edges by travelling "c"->"t"->"b"->"t".

This is an Eulerian path (it travels along all edges), and corresponds to the words cat,tab,bat.

Comment: +1 This should be accepted solution. I would just add that you don't actually need "each letter", but only set of first + last letters of the words. And astonishingly to me, from the proof above, solution to the problem has linear time complexity !

Comment: So in this case you can determine if the graph (using the model proposed by Kevin) is Hamiltonian in linear time. What's the properties of these kind of graphs that allow the complexity reduction?

Comment: @LeartS It is possible if the graph is a [line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph).  A graph is a line graph if and only if you can find a collection of cliques such that each vertex is in exactly 2 cliques.